# List in the range of values scaled according to another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list -
`x= [27, 28, 29, 28, 31, 32, 29, 30, 35, 36, 33, 37, 39]`
and a range - (0,2000)
How to make a new list with values in this range according to the list? Like 27 will be 0 and 39 will be 2000.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [27, 28, 29, 28, 31, 32, 29, 30, 35, 36, 33, 37, 39]
r = (0, 2000)

lower = min(x)
upper = max(x)

print ([(i - lower) * ((r[1] - r[0]) / (upper - lower)) + r[0] for i in x])
```

If you want integer values instead of floats, insert `int()` or `round()` inside the list comprehension.

*Edit:* I changed the code to provide a more generic solution that also works with other ranges beside (0, 2000).

Answer (score 1):

You tagged numpy, so here's an answer using it:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([27, 28, 29, 28, 31, 32, 29, 30, 35, 36, 33, 37, 39])
>>> 2000 * (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min())
array([   0.        ,  166.66666667,  333.33333333,  166.66666667,
        666.66666667,  833.33333333,  333.33333333,  500.        ,
       1333.33333333, 1500.        , 1000.        , 1666.66666667,
       2000.        ])
```

Comment: If i have numpy array like ```[[27, 28, 29, 28],[28,30,32,29],[31,32,28,33]]```, want to retain same structure but values in that range

Comment: @Prak The code above will work on that input as well. Try it out!

Comment: How about this? ```np.interp(x, (x.min(), x.max()), (0, 2000))```

Comment: @Prak That is the correct answer. Good find!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehension`, `min`, and `len`:

```py
>>[(i-min(x))*2000/(len(x)-1) for i in x]
[0.0, 166.66666666666666, 333.3333333333333, 166.66666666666666, 666.6666666666666, 833.3333333333334, 333.3333333333333, 500.0, 1333.3333333333333, 1500.0, 1000.0, 1666.6666666666667, 2000.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
>>> x = [27, 28, 29, 28, 31, 32, 29, 30, 35, 36, 33, 37, 39]
>>> y = [i* 2000/(len(x)-1) for i in range(len(x))]
>>> print(y)
>>> [0.0, 166.66666666666666, 333.3333333333333, 500.0, 666.6666666666666, 833.3333333333334, 1000.0, 1166.6666666666667, 1333.3333333333333, 1500.0, 1666.6666666666667, 1833.3333333333333, 2000.0]
```